# Can't set angular $scope variable from a callback function in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new in angular js. I am working with web Sql in a test project for learning purpose. My insert operation is working fine. My problem is when i fetch all the records then i can't store it in `$scope.todos=results.rows`
My code is

```
tx.transaction(sql,[],myCallback)
function myCallback(tx,results)
{
      console.log(results.rows); // shows objects in console
       $scope.todos=results.rows;
}
```

In view the todos is not working with ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It might help to show all of your controller, or service. If it's a controller make sure you included the $scope parameter for example:

```
.controller('MyController', function ($scope){

}))
```

If you are doing this inside a service, save it in a variable inside the service, then from a controller where the "$scope" is available include your service then call your variable containing the results. This will also be helpful if you need to share those results with other controllers at a later time.

```
.service('MyDataService',function(){
    var todos;

    return {
     .... set and get functions to access variable ...
      getTodos: function() {
        return todos;
      }
    };
  });
```

And in controller

```
   .controller('MyController', function ($scope, MyDataService){
       $scope.todos = MyDataService.getTodos()
    }))
```

There are also ways to get the $scope working in a service but I don't think it's a great idea.